# How to use vectorized NumPy operations on lambda functions that return constant values?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, vectorization

Why does this func return float?

```
func = lambda x: 1.
x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
func(x).shape
```

The result is

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I expect the following behaviour:

```
func = lambda x: 1. + 0*x
x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
func(x)
```

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

How to get the expected result without messing with the lambda function (i.e. without having to write `func = lambda x: 1. + 0*x`)?

The idea behind is that user passes this function to another function for further evaluation on a grid. I can not expect the user to white the constant function as `1 + 0*x`. What should I do?

Comment: This lambda function is always returning `1.`, which is a `float`, and a float has no shape... Note that the function is receiving `x`, but not doing anything with it. Also what is your expected output?

Comment: `Numpy.linspace` returns an array (an ndarray), you need to define a function that operates on such an array.

Comment: You are probably looking `np.full(10,1.)` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.full.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the `numpy.vectorize` method:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

```
func = lambda x: 1.
x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
x_func = np.vectorize(func)
x_func(x)
```

returns:`array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])`

Although assuming from your question you just want to create a array of 1*10 length initialised to `1.`

Why not use `np.full(10, 1.)`?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.full.html

Comment: The `np.vectorize` is what I was looking for. Thank you. I'm not just creating `np.ones`. This function a user-defined function used to evaluate other stuff.

Comment: And I just figured out that `np.vectorize(func,signature='()->(n)')` works if `func` returns a constant array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use lambda as persistent function. Your

   ```
   func = lambda x: 1.
   ```

   does absolutely the same as

   ```
   def func(x):
       return 1.
   ```
2. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Your lambda is returning `1.0`, w/o respecting parameters passed. Please clarify what logic you're expecting.